# discord.net c# :: user as IGuildUser returns null?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I've been working on getting my bot to add a role to a user.

Here's the bit of code that gets the user info.

Just for context args[1] would be a user's ID.

```
var user = _client.GetUser(Convert.ToUInt64(args[1]));
```

I did a check to see if it actually processed that properly by doing `Console.WriteLine(user.Username);` and it does spit out the username. Now the problem is when I try adding a role to said user by doing `await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);` it gives me an error claiming it's null.

I double checked by doing this:

```
if ((user as IGuildUser) is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User is null");
}
```

And it really is null.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Is it being done under a command? Because if it is, avoid using `client` and use `Contex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result will either `null` when either `user` already was `null` *or* the conversion of `user` to `IGuildUser` could not be achieved.
The last one, being the case in your current code

The `GetUser()` function returns you a `SocketUser`, which in place is a `IUser`, but not a `IGuildUser`.

If you want a `IGuildUser`, you will first have to determine from which server you want the `IGuildUser`. As there will be a different edition of the same user on each guild they are part of.

Assuming that you already know the guild for which you which to obtain, and you pass it along in the args as well, you could instead use something along the lines of.

```
var guild = _client.GetGuild(args[2]);
var guildUser = guild.GetUser(args[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. I'm not certain what the fault was, but I called _client for getting both guild and user.

Also quick note, if the input is a string (as mine was), you have to convert it to ulong. My code looks like this:

`var guild = _client.GetGuild(Convert.ToUInt64(args[2]));
var user = guild.GetUser(Convert.ToUInt64(args[1]));`

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking a user as a parameter I'd advise you get `IGuildUser` instead of a string. D.net will handle the co version and you will instantly have an `IGuildUser` instance.

It's also less prone to typos and so forth.

If you want it to be an ID and not a user for some reason you can request a ulong instead of a string which will not need you to use a conversion from `string` to `ulong`.